# Math induction problem (rules of exponents)

Tags: induction, exponentiation

Hello I am doing some induction problems, I have to prove that $3^{k+1}-1$ is a multiple of 2.

Suddenly they make this statement; $3^{k+1}$ is also $3 * 3^k$. Why is that?

Comment: $3^{k+1}-1 = (3^k-1)\cdot 3 + 2$.

Comment: @Hans Can you please tell us what is your definition of $n^k$?

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/mathematical-induction.html

Comment: look at this link and see the first eksample there you can see the statement i wa talking about

Comment: @Hansvakii What meaning do you give to the symbol $3^k$, where $k\in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Hmm, $3^k = \underbrace{3\cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot 3}_{k}$,  $\quad$ $3^{k+1} = \underbrace{3\cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot 3}_{k+1} = 3 \cdot \underbrace{3\cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot 3}_{k} = 3\cdot 3^k$.

Comment: Perhaps the question isn't "Why is $3^{k+1} = 3\cdot 3^k$?", but "Why is it that the Math Is Fun folks *suddenly* bring $3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^k$ into the argument?"

Comment: i cant really understand why  3^(k+1)=3⋅3^k ?

Comment: @Hansvakii In order to understand why a statement is true, you need to first understand what it says. To understand what it says, you need to understand what the entities involved mean. I realise now you don't know this and I'ma write up an answer explaining.

Comment: @GitGud yes k∈N.

Comment: I dont get why 3^(k+1)=3⋅3^k :S

Comment: With all due respect, if you don't understand why $3^{k+1}=3\cdot3^k$, you haven't got a snowball's chance of understanding induction. Spend some time learning school algebra first, then get back to induction when you're comfortable with exponents and such.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand why $3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^k$, you first need to understand what $3^{m}$ is, where $m$ is a natural number.

**By definition**: $3^0=1$ and $3^{m+1}=3\cdot 3^m$, for all $m\in \Bbb N_0\color{grey}{
=\{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}}$.

The equality $3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^k$ is a mere consequence of the definition above.

Some authors will write $3^m=\underbrace{3\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot 3}_{m\text{ factors}}$, but that's hardly rigorous and such a thing should only be written if the intended reader knows about the definition I used or if the reader doesn't know enough mathematics to deal with the definition above.

Comment: @Tomas Thanks.${}$

Comment: Underbraces are fun. :)

Comment: 3^(m+1)=3⋅3^m here u are just using this rule a^m*a^n=a^m+n right?

Comment: @Hansvakii Not really, no. It's the definition. If you know about that *rule*, then you can just use it with $a=3,m=k$ and $n=1$.

Comment: yeah i can see you are not using the rule sorry its very obvious.

Comment: @Hansvakii Do not apologize. It's only obvious after you realise what $3^k$ really means.

Comment: i think I get like when u have "term" 3^(m+1) then u know you get 2 "smaller terms" which are 3^m*3^1. is this the right way of thinking ?

Comment: @GitGud Just a small nit to pick. I think that readers who need help understanding what $3^{k+1}$ means are exactly the readers who may not have had enough mathematics to deal with your definition directly, and so may benefit from the (perhaps less rigorous) explanation with underbraces.

Comment: @ Joe 17, could you send a link so maybe i can understand what 3^(k+1) really means? But did you read my massage do i understand it in a right a way?

Comment: @Joe Could be, but if that's the case the OP can just use the rule he himself mentioned, namelythat $a^{m+n}=a^ma^n$.

Comment: anybody ???????

Comment: @Hansvakii $3^m=\underbrace{3\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot 3}_{m\text{ factors}}$, therefore $3^{k+1}=\underbrace{3\cdot3\cdot \ldots \cdot 3}_{k+1\text{ factors}}=3\cdot \underbrace{3\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot 3}_{k\text{ factors}}=3\cdot 3^k$.

Comment: okay I think i get it.